# Where does this transmission rate come from?

Tags: transmission

In a webpage I saved from long time ago:

> Many people are happy when they purchase their first scanner because
>   they can now attach images to the Email they send to friends and
>   family. Little do they know that the art of scanning photographs into
>   clear, crisp image files of a small size (**50 KB** or less) requires
>   skill and an understanding of their scanner hardware and image editing
>   software.
>
> (NOTE: The small file size as given above is recommended because it
>   only requires about 10 seconds to transmit a file of this size through
>   their modem; hence, neither sender nor receiver will grow impatient
>   waiting. The 10 second time is calculated as follows for a typical
>   **56.6 Kbps** modem connection:  **50 KBytes x 8 bits/Byte / 40,000 bits/sec = 10 sec**. The discussion below reveals that if you're not careful, you could easily spend 100 times longer than the above 10 seconds waiting
>   for the file to transmit to the recipient!)

I wonder where "40,000 bits/sec" comes from in the calculation for the time for transmission? it isn't equal to "56.6Kbps". Or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A 56k modem would virtually never provide a 56k connection due to a whole raft of issues - including impedence mismatch and other cabling faults and hardware incompatibilities.  40-48k seemed to be the norm from memory - connections over 53k were very, very rare.

Also, most modems followed the "V90" standard which was asymetrical and limited upload speeds to 33.6k - not 48k of the "V92" standard.

[  Source: I used to run an ISP in the days of dialup and invested quite heavily in special 56k capable modems - for a 56k connection the ISP could not use a standard modem they needed to use a 64k ISDN channel ].

Also, this whole post is simplistic (you could argue flawed if you want to be pedantic) - That 50kb * 8kbits is naive as it ignores the overheads of sending the file - this is quite significant on an Internet connection but even on a basic connection it was non-trivial - think an overhead of 10%

As someone else has posted, if the image is being sent in an email, there is substantial overhead in converting the file from 8 bits of ASCII per character to something which falls in the acceptable space for email (readable characters, line limits).  This could vary by encoding method - there is more then 1, but in the region of 33% overhead.

Answer (score 2):

#### I wonder where "40,000 bits/sec" comes from in the transmission calculation?

A 56.6 Kbps modem connection uses V.92.

The upload speed is a max of 48 kbit/s, but at the expense of download rates.

> **A 48 kbit/s upstream rate would reduce the downstream as low as 40
> kbit/s due to echo on the telephone line.**

---

**Using digital lines and PCM (V.90/92)**

> The International Telecommunication Union (ITU) announced the draft of
> a new 56 kbit/s standard, V.90, in February 1998 with strong industry
> support.[4] Incompatible with either existing standard,[4] it was an
> amalgam of both which was designed to allow both types of modem to be
> converted to it by a firmware upgrade. This V.90 standard was approved
> in September 1998, and widely adopted by ISPs and consumers.[4] Later
> in V.92, the digital PCM technique was applied to increase the upload
> speed to a maximum of 48 kbit/s, but at the expense of download rates.
> **A 48 kbit/s upstream rate would reduce the downstream as low as 40
> kbit/s due to echo on the telephone line.**

Source [Modem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the 56600 bps rate should be used in this calculation. However, e-mail attachments typically use base64 encoding where each 3 8-bit bytes are encoded by 4 7-bit ASCII characters, and most e-mail clients can only handle 8-bit characters anyway, so the net result is transforming 3 bytes into 4, and the effective transfer rate will be

```
56600 / 4 * 3 = 42450 (bps)
```

PS. As @David's answer points out, a 56.6k modem has its upload speed limited at 48000 bps. Applying the same "correction" for this rate gives

```
48000/ 4 * 3 = 36000 (bps)
```

Still, none of these calculations give the exact 40000 bps result, so I suppose it's an approximative value.

Comment: Thanks, but why "/4*3"?

Comment: E-mail attachments typically use [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding where each 3 8-bit bytes are encoded by 4 7-bit ASCII characters, and most e-mail clients can only handle 8-bit characters anyway, so the net result is transforming 3 bytes into 4.

Comment: It might be a good idea to add this explanation to your answer.